# Reading a json file and encoding problems

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I would like to parse a JSON file and print `source` in this code fragment :

```
{
        "trailers": {
            "quicktime": [], 
            "youtube": [
                {
                    "source": "mmNhzU6ySL8", 
                    "type": "Trailer", 
                    "name": "Trailer 1", 
                    "size": "HD"
                }, 
                {
                    "source": "CPTIgILtna8", 
                    "type": "Trailer", 
                    "name": "Trailer 2", 
                    "size": "Standard"
                }
            ], 
            "id": 27205
        },
```

I wrote this code :

```
for item in j:        
        if item['trailers']:
            e = item['trailers']
            for k,value in e.iteritems():
                if k == "youtube":
                    for innerk, innerv in k.iteritems():
                        if innerk == "source" :
                            print innerv
```

unfortunately I can't resolve this error :

```
for innerk, innerv in k.iteritems():

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Have you tried python's [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the JSON is formatted properly, the problem is that your code includes this check:

```
if k == "youtube":
    for innerk, innerv in k.iteritems():
```

Given that you just asked for `k` to be `"youtube"` (an instance of `str` or `unicode`), it won't make sense to expect `k` to have an `iteritems` method.

I believe instead you are expecting the associated `dict` that would have come along with `k`, something like this:

```
if k == "youtube":
    for innerk, innerv in value.iteritems():
```

I'm noticing from your JSON, though, that it looks like you should expect multiple `dict` variables to be loaded as the `list`-typed value for the case when `k == "youtube"`. In that case, you'll need to iterate over those elements first, asking for each one's `iteritems` separately:

```
if k == "youtube":
    for each_dict in value:
        for innerk, innerv in each_dict.iteritems():
```

or something along those lines. The final full code would be:

```
for item in j:        
    if item['trailers']:
        e = item['trailers']
        for k,value in e.iteritems():
            if k == "youtube":
                for each_dict in value:
                    for innerk, innerv in each_dict.iteritems():
                        if innerk == "source" :
                            print innerv
```

Aside from the first-order question, you should also take a look at the `dict` type's built-in method `get`, which allows you to safely get items from a dictionary and handle the case when they are missing gracefully. In your code, when you say `if item['trailers']:` this may not behave the way you expect.

First, if `trailers` is not a key to the dictionary, it will generate a `KeyError` instead of just skipping that conditional block. Secondly, if the value stored for the key value `trailers` evaluates to `False` in a `bool` context, the conditional block will also be skipped, even if you had wanted to handle it differently (for example, suppose that `None` is a sentinel value signaling that there is no data for `trailers` in that case, but it's due to a specific error that you want to log.

Meanwhile, if it's just an empty `dict` then that does mean you should simply skip the conditional block). This may not matter much in one-off data exploration, but in general it's good to become automatically conditioned to avoid these sorts of pitfalls, especially when the built-in types themselves make it very easy to handle things more gracefully.

Given all of this, a more Pythonic approach might be as follows:

```
for item in j:    
    y_tube = item.get('trailers', {}).get("youtube", [])
    for each_dict in y_tube:
        print each_dict.get("source", "Warning: no entry found for 'source'")
```

Comment: I've got this :  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` and I am trying to fix it .

Comment: That is what my middle update covers. Notice that the JSON for `"youtube"` is a `list` with two dictionaries. It is not just a dictionary. So `value` will be a `list`. That means you further need to iterate over those `list` elements (the part in my answer where I wrote "`for each_dict in value:`") and only *then* can you finally do the inner-most loop to print the data stored at the key `"source"`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line:

```
for k,value in e.iteritems()
```

So clearly, `k` is a key (a unicode string in your case). You clearly know this, with your comparison of `if k == "youtube"`.
Unicode strings don't have the `iteritems()` method.

I have a feeling that what you're looking for is this:

```
for k,value in e.iteritems()
    for innerk,innerv in value.iteritems():
        # do stuff
```